# Writing to single range ignoring specified range

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a set of values to a Google sheet based on an example in the docs. When I try to place the data further down in the sheet, the range information seems to be ignored. So the following:

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="Sheet1!A19:D5",
valueInputOption="RAW", body=body).execute()
```

Does not result in the data being written starting on A19. It writes it to A5. No matter what range I feed it, it writes to A5. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser here is probably guessing you meant A5:D19, since A19:D5 makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Mea culpa. Too much caffeine and not enough sleep. I didn't even notice they simple typo. You are correct, I'm feeding the interpreter nonsense and it is trying to make sense of it. Thanks for pointing it out.